# How to get the path to a file outside the root folder in React application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app

This is simplified folder structure in my React application created with the create-react-app. For the back-end I'm using the Express framework.

```
└── ReactApp/
    ├── client/
    |  ├── node_modules/
    |  ├── public/
    |  └── src/
    |      └── components/
    |         └── component.js
    └── server/
       ├── index.js
       └── Uploads/
           └── file.txt
```

Inside `component.js` file I want to define the path to the `file.txt` file located to the `server/Uploads` folder.

```
 handleClick() {
        const pathToFile = '../../server/Uploads/file.txt;
        this.setState({ input: pathToFile})
  }
```

The issue is that this defined path cannot locate the txt file inside the Uploads folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
handleClick() {
   const pathToFile = '../../../server/Uploads/file.txt';
   this.setState({ input: pathToFile})
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting   ``` GET http://localhost:3000/server/Uploads/file.txt 404 (Not Found) ```

Comment: your server should be configured to serve static files. eg:- files inside static folder

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to configure ExpressJS to serve static files inside the Uploads folder.

**index.js**

```
app.use(express.static('Uploads'));
```

and then change the path inside the **component.js** file.

```
handleClick() {
    const pathToFile = 'file.txt';
    this.setState({ input: pathToFile})
  }
```